# How to determine the amount of memory required by my char*?

Tags: c, memory-management

I've this simple program and need to know on which basis should I choose the have for the variable (`howToPredectThisNumber`) (i.e. the size of the `char*` string).

And Which is best to choose in this case, `char[]` or `char*`??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* name;
}Emp;

void init(Emp** emp)
{
    int howToPredectThisNumber = 50;
    *emp = malloc(sizeof(Emp));
    (*emp)->name = NULL;
    (*emp)->name = calloc(howToPredectThisNumber, sizeof(char*));
}

void release(Emp** emp)
{
    free((*emp)->name);
    free(*emp);
}

void setName(Emp* emp, char* newName)
{
    strcpy(emp->name, newName);
}
char* getName(Emp* emp)
{
    return emp->name;
}

int main(void)
{
    Emp* emp;
    init(&emp);
    setName(emp, "Muhammad            Abdullah");
    printf("%s", getName(emp));
    release(&emp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have almost 90 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you could look at the the answers you have been given to see if any are acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should delay that deduction until you know what you want to copy:

```
void setName(Emp* emp, char* newName)
{ 
    free(emp->name);
    emp->name = malloc( strlen( newName ) + 1 );
    strcpy(emp->name, newName);
}
```

Comment: I agree. Also, though @sharptooth didn't explicitly point it out, using `malloc` rather than `calloc` is fine here. If you do want to use `calloc`, your second parameter should be `sizeof(char)` rather than `sizeof(char *)`. Of course `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 anyway.

Comment: Personally, for calloc I would always use  `<Type> *x = calloc (len, sizeof (*x));' It avoids confusion and allows for easy changing of <Type> in future.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pointers less and use strdup instead of malloc+strlen+strcpy as thats what it is for.

A better solution is to realise that Emp isn't valid with a name and make sure its provided when created. If you forget to provide a name it won't compile instead of causing a segmentation fault when you run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char* name;
} Emp;

Emp *create(char * name) {
    Emp *emp = (Emp *) malloc(sizeof (Emp));
    emp->name = strdup(name);
    return emp;
}

void release(Emp* emp) {
    free(emp->name);
    free(emp);
}

void setName(Emp* emp, char* newName) {
    free(emp->name);
    emp->name = strdup(newName);
}

char* getName(Emp* emp) {
    return emp->name;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Emp* emp = create("Muhammad            Abdullah");
    printf("%s", getName(emp));
    release(emp);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```